# How to Do a SUM and Group Data by Each Month

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I'm creating a View in Oracle 10g. See the attached image for example of my data. I want to be able to do a SUM on all the records that have same ProjectCode and Month. My query below still shows me individual months for each ProjectCode listed separately:

```
SELECT ProjectCode,  ItemNumber, ItemCode, Type, SUM(Estimate), Month
FROM ProjectDetails
<bunch of INNER JOINS HERE>
WHERE ProjectDetails.ProjectCode=AllDetails.ProjectCode 
GROUP BY ProjectCode,  ItemNumber, ItemCode, Type, Estimate, Month;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group by` the things you want to see.  Remove the extraneous columns from both the `select` and the `group by`:

```
SELECT ProjectCode, SUM(Estimate), Month
FROM ProjectDetails
<bunch of INNER JOINS HERE>
WHERE ProjectDetails.ProjectCode=AllDetails.ProjectCode 
GROUP BY ProjectCode,  Month;
```

EDIT:

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT ProjectCode,  ItemNumber, ItemCode, Type, SUM(Estimate), Month
FROM ProjectDetails
<bunch of INNER JOINS HERE>
WHERE ProjectDetails.ProjectCode=AllDetails.ProjectCode 
GROUP BY ProjectCode,  ItemNumber, ItemCode, Type, Month;
```

Note:  All I did was remove the `estimate` from the `group by`.

You should also put the join conditions in the `from` clause, not in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I also want to see rest of the columns.

Comment: @user2425909 . . . It makes no sense to see the rest of the columns, because they would have multiple values within a project code.

Comment: But the user requests to see that data in tge View I'm creating for them.

Comment: Put this query in sub select and join again with main table to get all columns